# I want to add an object to my list but the way the nested loops are organized makes this impossible (C#)

Tags: c#, loops, nested, treeview, nodes

So I'm making a program that has several categories with multiple notes stored in it. I'm a student and we got the assignment to work with the localdb of SQL server to save our categories and notes. The program shows the categories and notes by using the treeview control.

Now I'm trying to make a searchbar for my notes. It has to filter on the title of the note.

My question is, how can I get all the notes from a category and add them to the same category? Now all the notes are displayed in different categories but with the same name. This is because my main loop processes the notes and the inner-loop processes the category.

When I put "categoriesUI1.Categories.Add(category);" behind the while-loop I only see 1 category with 1 note because the while-loop of the notes is processed first.

Here are some extra screenshots to give you a better idea of how my program works:

Before filtering:
https://gyazo.com/cea5c4d9ff18fb93c9f47cf336942bc9

After filtering on 'test2':
https://gyazo.com/282240e5f1a754389688c68257893d92

```
connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=dbNotes;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.SelectedNode = categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.TopNode;
        int count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = count; i > 0; i = count)
            {
                categoriesUI1.Categories.RemoveAt(0);
                count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;
            }
        }

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand commandNote = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Cat_ID, Titel, Text, Created FROM tblNote WHERE Titel LIKE '%" + searchBarUI1.getTextValue() + "%'", connection);
        SqlDataReader readerNote = commandNote.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerNote.HasRows)
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            while (readerNote.Read())
            {
                int id = readerNote.GetInt32(0);
                int Cat_id = readerNote.GetInt32(1);
                string title = readerNote.GetString(2);
                string text = readerNote.GetString(3);
                DateTime created = readerNote.GetDateTime(4);
                string Cat_title = "";

                SqlCommand commandCategory = new SqlCommand("SELECT Titel FROM tblCategory WHERE ID = " + Cat_id, connection);
                SqlDataReader readerCategory = commandCategory.ExecuteReader();
                if (readerCategory.HasRows)
                {
                    while (readerCategory.Read())
                    {
                        Cat_title = readerCategory.GetString(0);
                        category = new Category(Cat_id, Cat_title);
                    }
                }
                Note note;
                note = new Note(id, title, text, created);
                category.Notes.Add(note);
                readerCategory.Close();
                categoriesUI1.Categories.Add(category);
            }

        }
        readerNote.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

i gave you my idae

1.you get all Cates by Searchkey.
2.get Add all Notes filetered by searchKey and Cat_id ,add them to proper Cate

detail is follow,Just some ideas ,not tested yet .hope it helps.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// initail your  UI
    /// </summary>
    void ini()
    {


        connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=dbNotes;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.SelectedNode = categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.TopNode;
        int count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = count; i > 0; i = count)
            {
                categoriesUI1.Categories.RemoveAt(0);
                count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;
            }
        }

    }







    /// <summary>
    /// this is for add all searchressult Cates to to Treeview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sKey"></param>
    void SearchCate(string sKey)
    {
           connection.Open();
        SqlCommand commandCategory = new SqlCommand("SELECT Titel FROM tblCategory WHERE ID in ( 
SELECT ID  FROM tblNote WHERE Titel LIKE '%" + sKey +
                                "%') " + Cat_id, connection);


        SqlDataReader readerCategory = commandCategory.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerCategory.HasRows)
        {
            while (readerCategory.Read())
            {
                Cat_title = readerCategory.GetString(0);
                category = new Category(Cat_id, Cat_title); // new category
                categoriesUI1.Categories.Add(category);

                // then add your note's search result here to eavcgorhe

                AddNoteToACateBySearchKey(sKey,category);

            }
        }



    }



    /// <summary>
    /// add all searchresult note to cate 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sKey"></param>
    /// <param name="Parent"></param>

    void AddNoteToACateBySearchKey(string sKey, Category Parent )
    {


        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand commandNote = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Cat_ID, Titel, Text, Created FROM tblNote WHERE Titel LIKE '%" + sKey + "%' and Cat_ID='" + Parent.Cat_id + "' ", connection);
        SqlDataReader readerNote = commandNote.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerNote.HasRows)
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            while (readerNote.Read())
            {
                int id = readerNote.GetInt32(0);
                int Cat_id = readerNote.GetInt32(1);
                string title = readerNote.GetString(2);
                string text = readerNote.GetString(3);
                DateTime created = readerNote.GetDateTime(4);
                string Cat_title = "";



                Note note;
                note = new Note(id, title, text, created); // new note
                category.Notes.Add(note);
                readerCategory.Close();




            }



        }

        readerNote.Close();
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a note only if the Cat_ID corresponds with the ID of the current category. Now the main loop processes the categories and the inner-loop processes the notes.

```
connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=dbNotes;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.SelectedNode = categoriesUI1.tvwCategories.TopNode;
        int count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = count; i > 0; i = count)
            {
                categoriesUI1.Categories.RemoveAt(0);
                count = categoriesUI1.Categories.Count;
            }
        }

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand commandCategory = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Titel from tblCategory", connection);
        SqlDataReader readerCategory = commandCategory.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerCategory.HasRows)
        {
            while (readerCategory.Read())
            {
                int id = readerCategory.GetInt32(0);
                string titel = readerCategory.GetString(1);
                Category category = new Category(id, titel);

                SqlCommand commandNote = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Cat_ID, Titel, Text, Created FROM tblNote WHERE Titel LIKE '%" + searchBarUI1.getTextValue() + "%'", connection);
                SqlDataReader readerNote = commandNote.ExecuteReader();
                if (readerNote.HasRows)
                {
                    while (readerNote.Read())
                    {
                        int catID = readerNote.GetInt32(1);
                        if (catID == id)
                        {
                            int noteID = readerNote.GetInt32(0);
                            string noteTitel = readerNote.GetString(2);
                            string noteText = readerNote.GetString(3);
                            DateTime noteCreated = readerNote.GetDateTime(4);
                            Note note = new Note(noteID, noteTitel, noteText, noteCreated);
                            category.Notes.Add(note);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(category.Notes.Count > 0)
                    categoriesUI1.Categories.Add(category);
            }
        }
```